# Sub Category product can't be view in the product page

Tags: magento2, product-page

**Magento 2 and using porto theme**

Sub Category product can't be view in the product page

**i'm attached the all screenshot admin and front end**

in admin to add the product in select the category  not viewed in the page

[image]

[image]

**admin side**

[image]

**admin in stock**

[image]

**Search results show the product but Sub Category product can't be view in the product page**

[image]

**Category page in admin side**

[image]

Comment: make sure you rebuilt your indexes.

Comment: yes i do reindexing

Comment: Does it show in admin side fine?

Comment: yes admin side show the product

Comment: Make sure these products are online, in stock, available for your store?

Comment: Make sure those two products are online, in stock, visibility catalog,search for your store and qty > 0.

Comment: yes it is in the in stock

Comment: i add the screenshot in the admin product page

Comment: Can you show the screen-sort of your "Display Seeting" tab of that category.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya ok

Comment: Please refer the this and verify the settings.- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927658/products-is-not-showing-up-on-magento2-subcategory

Comment: @DhirenVasoya i do that all think but not showing

Comment: use see the screen sort

Answer (score 1):

For a category to be accessible in the frontend of website, it needs to be a child of a root category and that root category must be set a root for the current website.

```
System->Store management
```

Comment: please go thorough this link if you  have idea reply me"https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250625/sql-error-while-adding-any-products-to-category-m2"

Answer (score 0):

re-indexing will solve the issue, also changed "status" from "out of stock" to "in stock" of product

Comment: i' m do re-indexing and deploy static-content also

Comment: Ok just a minute I am working on the issue.

Comment: ok.. i'm waiting..

Comment: Make sure that scope of the category is for the website or global

Comment: that category and product show in the search and the main category page.. it only not showing in the sub category page you the screenshot

Comment: i'm adding the image in the Category page in the admin side

Comment: If you want checking product to subcategory, go to Catalog->Manage Categories->Select your category, open tab Display Settings and change option "Is Anchor" to "Yes". Save category.

Comment: i add the Is Anchor tag also but showing the product

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50594/discussion-between-gokul-k-and-mrunmay-deswandikar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Step 1 : Remove all the product from that category and reindex all one by one.

Step 2 : Add those product back in that category and reindex again one by one.

Comment: i have 200 product in the site.. i also remove the sub-category product and re indexing and cache clear and add the that sub-category it not working